# Calculating area of voronoi polygons from real life data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, coordinate-system, area, voronoi-thiessen

I have an area, which I divided into voronoi polygons using data points. I have no problem creating the polygons.

Now the data points are on a coordinate system, where every degree represents one meter. I know try to use the $area command to get the area, but the answer is way to large.

To clarify my problem I will try to give a bit of an example:

[image]

This image gives the spatial division of a set of data points, boreholes in this case. They all influence a certain area. This area is defined as their voronoi cell. I have created these cells:

[image]

What I now want to know is the area of the polygons. I have tried to use the command $area, but this gives an area which is way too big. I know this because I  did some basic area calculations on some of the simpeler polygons. For example the area for the triangular polygon in the bottom left (BH1101) I calculated to be about 695,000 m2. However using the $area command give me an area of 8.6140950578267e+15 which is in no unit I know equal to what I calculated.

Why is this and how can I fix this?

The data comes from an excel sheet which I converted into a .txt file and put into Qgis. The location is somewhere in Germany, if need be I can get a more precise location, but it shouldnt matter for the results. I run Qgis on the standard settings, using the CRS (WGS84:4326).

Comment: which CRS are you using (project, input points and output?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn more about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include more information about your CRS and the data you are working with, as well as a sample of your data - the polygons, the areas, what you think the area should be (and how you calculated that)

Comment: Right-click your polygon layer, go to `Save As...`, assign a new CRS (try `EPSG:25832` which is UTM zone 32N) and save it as a new shapefile. Load this back into QGIS, change the project CRS also to `EPSG:25832` then try running `$area` in the field calculator again to see if the results are closer to what you are expecting.

Comment: You are using a CRS which does not apply to the region you are working with. This of course, gives a lot of errors when calculating/measuring areas. Use the correct CRS for you area.